# Ensure uniqueness of relationship objects in RestKit

Tags: ios, json, swift, restkit

Is it possible to define an object mapping that ensures uniqueness of a CoreData object based **not on attributes** of the corresponding JSON object, but on **attributes of related** objects?

#### In short

Basically, I want to set identification attributes that are attributes of relationships (`objectA` and `objectB` are relationships).

```
mapping.identificationAttributes = ["objectA.id", "objectB.id"]
```

#### Extended explanation

The scenario is that on the server side, a certain *relationship object* does not have its own primary key but it is uniquely identified by the composition of two relationships. Example:

```
{
    "objectA": {
        "id": 1
    },
    "objectB": {
        "id": 2
    },
    "rel": {
        "object_a_id": 1, // foreign key
        "object_b_id": 2, // foreign key
        "awesomeness_in_percent": 100 // regular attribute
    }
}
```

For `objectA` and `objectB` I can create mappings that have their `identificationAttributes` set to `["id"]`. **How would I do that with `rel`** if I don't want to *store the foreign keys as attributes* but have `id_a` and `id_b` resolve to actual relationships?

I tried setting `identificationAttributes` to `["objectA.id", "objectB.id"]` (`objectA` and `objectB` being the relationships) but this fails with the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
'Invalid attribute 'objectA.id': no attribute was found for the given name
in the 'Rel' entity.
```

The problem is not related to the `id` naming as in my model, this attribute is called something else.